# Cross-Platform file type association

Tags: operating-system

I'm currently working on a BitTorrent client written in Java and I was wondering how to associate it with the *.torrent files on Linux, Windows and Mac.

Specifically I'm looking for two operations on the three OS:

- Find associated program for a given file type (either MIME or File extension)
- Set the associated program for a given file type

Comment: I think GNOME and KDE use separate file-associations, so actually 4.

Comment: @Mechanical they both follow the same freedesktop.org mime type database standard so still only 3

Comment: Isn't there the freedesktop.org portland project that tries to unify them?

Comment: I've been digging into the portland project, but it still is incredibly confusing. I just cant get my custom client described as a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` to show up in `gvfs-mime --query application/x-bittorrent`.